# why is my newly installed nexus not accessible via url

Tags: installation, nexus

I just installed Nexus on Amazon Linux server allowing all traffic in the security group. I am able to ssh into it.
I am able start it on the cli. But I am unable to access it via the url using server_ip:8081.
Error message: **Server_ip refused to connect**
When I do **netstat -tulpn |grep LISTEN**  I see that it is not listening on port8081